# Featured Image, and Image in post

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I have a bit of dilemma regarding featured image. Here's my situation.
I'm currently using featured image tied to a post to display on the home page, and on the single post page as well.

However I've run into an issue where I'm using a featured image, but the post also has an image, in this case, I don't want to show the featured image on the post page, but only the image that is in the post.

I still require the feature image for the home page (as it's a different image then the post page image).

Does that make sense?

Bottom line 
-all post require a feature image
-feature image used in homepage, and on single post page
-however if post has an image don't display the feature image

Any help?

Comment: So you're looking for code logic that grabs the first image of the post and displays that instead of the featured image? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

on the template of the page that you are trying to pull the first image on,(if its the post itself, then single.php) you could use the following code instead of the_post_thumbnail

```
function echo_first_image( $postID ) {
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $postID,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
);

$attachments = get_children( $args );

if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' )  ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' ) : wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );

        echo '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID ) . '" class="current">';
    }
}
}
```